# Hide or Show Drop down box pending on Radio Button - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

not sure what is wrong with this jquery code: http://jsfiddle.net/aCABM/

I want to to grey out the dropdown menu when 'yes' is selected. When no is selected it can be selected if the user so wishes.

Comment: made some changes to your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/ylokesh/aCABM/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the elements by radio button `name` there is no need to select them individually by there ids and use `prop` instead of `attr` since you are manipulating its `disabled` property. Try this.

```
$(function(){
    $("input[name='discount']").click(function() {
        $("#discountselection").prop("disabled", this.value == 'Yes');
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/aCABM/7/)**

In your fiddle there were few issues.

1. Missed to include jQuery library
2. You cannot just begin your markup with `td`, it should be enclosed with `table` and `tr` element.
3. In the Js window you just have to put your js, no need to have `script` tags.

Comment: worked a treat. Also if I added another value to dropdown called 'please select' and I wanted to make a validation error if 'please select' was selected when submitted but ignored if 'no' was selected (as please select would be greyed out) how would i do this?

Comment: You can check for `if(!$("#discountselection").prop("disabled") && $("#discountselection").val() == 'please select'){ //alert('Please select'); }`.

Comment: :). I have added another drop down. How would I use a div class instead of div id so that i do not have add each id individually into jquery?

Comment: Just use the class selector instead of id. If this answer has solved your problem you accept this and create a new question for other problems.

Comment: I cannot seem to get it to work. it is greyed out whether i select yes or no.

do I download http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js
save it as jquery.js
and add  <script src="jquery.js"></script> into my code?

Comment: In my demo it works as expected ans you even commented `worked a treat`.

Comment: i thought it was in html but when i uploaded it both were greyed whether i selected yes or no

Answer (score 0):

check updated code here

http://jsfiddle.net/ylokesh/aCABM/1/

Answer (score 0):

Update code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/aCABM/6/[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/aCABM/6/)

You need to wrap your code in a `$(document).ready()` function, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Yes").click(function() {
        $("#discountselection").attr("disabled", false);
        //$("#discountselection").show(); //To Show the dropdown
    });
    $("#No").click(function() {
        $("#discountselection").attr("disabled", true);
        //$("#discountselection").hide();//To hide the dropdown
    });
})
```

Also, you didn't setup jsFiddle correctly, it required jQuery library and (document)ready()

Comment: Im still having issues. if i select yes or no they are both still greyed out. Im guessing something to do with the library. CAn you confirm I have done it right, I downloaded code from jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js save it as jquery.js and add <script src="jquery.js"></script> into my code?  what is (document)ready() you say above?

Comment: @user1188711 - glad I could help you. If my answer helped you, or if anybody else's did, can you accept it by clicking the tick button. It gives me a point but most importantly, it closes the question. Good luck with the rest of your project

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
$("#Yes").click(function() {
    $("#discountselection").show();
});
$("#No").click(function() {
    $("#discountselection").hide();
});
```

and remove the `disable="disable"`.

Good-Luck !